# Selecting inside a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is the html code

```
<div class="extra-sub-block sub-block-experience">
    <h6 style="display:inline;" id="exp-pos-0" class="extra-sub-block-head sub-block-head-experience">CEO</h6>
</div>
<div class="extra-sub-block sub-block-experience">
    <h6 style="display:inline;" id="exp-pos-1" class="extra-sub-block-head sub-block-head-experience">COO</h6>
</div>
```

There are several such similar structures. Now I try to extract the values from each block.

```
var temp=document.getElementsByClassName('sub-block-experience');
var result=$(temp[0]+"#exp-pos-0");
```

This throws an error. I followed [selecting element inside another DOM](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/)

I also tried

```
var temp=document.getElementsByClassName('sub-block-experience');
var result=temp[0].find('h6');
```

This doesn't work as well. What am I doing wrong here. Help?

Comment: as you already have tagged jquery, why don't you use it? like $(".sub-block-experience").find("h6") etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting the values from all blocks, you can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function as follows:

```
var results = $('.extra-sub-block-head').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
})
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Esg4U/)

*side note:* Since `id` is unique in a document, you can directly access the element using `id` selector like `var result= $("#exp-pos-0");`instead of  `var result=$(temp[0]+"#exp-pos-0");`

Comment: Since the actual data is too large to handle this way, I want it to be more genric

Comment: Nice edit. But in actual code I have more than one tag(dynamic) inside each div(which is also dynamic). So can I make a similar kind of selection with the use of "sub-block-experience" class and group them as blocks according to the no of such dynamic divs?

Comment: It'll be easier if you say what you want to achieve. do you want to get the value inside all such `<h6>` in page, or something else..?

Comment: I want to extract each info separately

Comment: @aravindbharathy i didn't get what you meant by *separately* because the code above returns an array of all values, not just single value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56592/discussion-between-aravind-bharathy-and-tilwin-joy).

Comment: @aravindbharathy you can return a json including the information of each block like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Esg4U/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try, `var result=$(temp[0]).find('h6');`

Even, in the documentation link that you gave in question, it shows that you should wrap your result from `document.getElementById` in `$()` to be applied with jQuery. What it does is, that it converts the native javascript object into a jquery object.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ErRohitAgg/yj39y/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function testIt(){
    var tags, index;
    tags = document.getElementsByTagName('h6');
  for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    //do something ...
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you are trying to get ceo and coo?.If that's the case then with jquery:

```
var x= $('.extra-sub-block h6');
//values are
$(x[O]).html();
$(x[1]).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use plain javascript:

```
var result = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-block-experience h6');
```

Or if you like it separate:

```
var temp = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-block-experience');
var result = [];
for(var i = 0, elem; elem = temp[i]; i++) {
  result = result.concat(elem.querySelectorAll('h6'));
}
```

But be aware of the browser compatability of [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).